# Disable @PreAuthorize annotation when running a profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber, integration-testing

I have written API functional test cases for Spring boot Application using cucumber test framework. The tests are executed after starting the spring boot application in a profile with dedicated configurations for test cases, using the following command:

```
mvn spring-boot:start -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=test -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--spring.config.name=application-test --spring.config.location=./src/test/resources/application-test.yaml" test spring-boot:stop -DskipTests=false
```

The API call is made from test cases once the spring application is started and the responses are validated in the tests.

I have disabled the security in test cases using the custom WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter given below:

```
@TestConfiguration
@Order(1)
@Profile("test")
public class TestSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
    }

}
```

The security is disabled. But there are some controllers where the role is checked with @PreAuthorize annotation. The calls made to the controller with @PreAuthorize annotation is failed with the following error:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1689838624242,
    "errorType": "UNKNOWN",
    "errors": [
        "Access is denied"
    ]
}
```

Tried several options to disabled to PreAuthorize field to specific profile but none of them worked. Appreciate any idea on how to disable the @PreAuthorize check for a selected profile or in test cases with Cucumber.

The options already tried:

1. set `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` in test. It didn't work
2. Referred to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561974/restassured-how-to-disable-preauthorize-when?rq=4). My spring boot application is secured with Oauth2, which I disabled in tests. so sending basic auth credentials will not work.

Comment: `prePostEnabled = true` means that it is enabled not disabled, you should use `false` instead.

Comment: modified it. it didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Setup test security context in a `@Given` step instead of disabling security.

Sample taken from [this README](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-addons-oauth2-test/Cucumber.md) I wrote (at a time Keycloak adapters for Spring where not deprecated):

Gherkin feature:

```
Feature: Testing a secured REST API
  Users should be able to GET greetings only if authenticated

  Scenario: Authorized users should be greeted
    Given the following user roles:
      | ROLE_user   |
      | ROLE_TESTER |
    When a get request is sent to greeting endpoint
    Then a greeting is returned

  Scenario: Unauthorized users should not be able to access greetings
    Given user is not authenticated
    When a get request is sent to greeting endpoint
    Then 401 is returned
```

The following uses some code from `com.c4-soft.springaddons:spring-addons-oauth2-test`, a lib of mine published on maven-central, to ease defining OpenID claims. You can skip this dependency if you are not interested in claims details (if authorities and user name are enough):

```java
public class JwtTestingBuilder {
    protected final OpenidClaimSetBuilder claimsBuilder;
    private final Set<String> authorities;
    private String bearerString = "machin.truc.chose";
    private Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>(Map.of("machin", "truc"));

    public JwtTestingBuilder() {
        this.claimsBuilder = new OpenidClaimSetBuilder().subject(Defaults.SUBJECT).name(Defaults.AUTH_NAME);
        this.authorities = new HashSet<>(Defaults.AUTHORITIES);
    }

    public JwtAuthenticationToken build() {
        final var claims = claimsBuilder.build();
        final var iat = Instant.now();
        final var exp = iat.plusMillis(60000);
        final var jwt = new Jwt(bearerString, iat, exp, headers, claims);
        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toSet()), claims.getName());
    }

    public JwtTestingBuilder authorities(String... authorities) {
        return authorities(Stream.of(authorities));
    }

    public JwtTestingBuilder authorities(Stream<String> authorities) {
        this.authorities.clear();
        this.authorities.addAll(authorities.toList());
        return this;
    }

    public JwtTestingBuilder claims(Consumer<OpenidClaimSetBuilder> tokenBuilderConsumer) {
        tokenBuilderConsumer.accept(claimsBuilder);
        return this;
    }

    public JwtTestingBuilder bearerString(String bearerString) {
        this.bearerString = bearerString;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Steps:

```java
public class GreetingControllerSuite {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    MvcResult result;

    @Given("user is not authenticated")
    public void unauthenticatedUser() {
        TestSecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    }

    @Given("the following user roles:")
    public void authenticateAsUser(List<String> rolesTable) {
        TestSecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        final Stream<String> roles = rolesTable.stream().map(String::trim);
        TestSecurityContextHolder.setAuthentication(new JwtTestingBuilder().authorities(roles).build());
    }

    @When("a get request is sent to greeting endpoint")
    public void getGreet() throws Exception {
        result = mockMvc.perform(get("/greet")).andReturn();
    }

    @Then("401 is returned")
    public void unauthorizedStatus() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(401, result.getResponse().getStatus());
    }

    @Then("a greeting is returned")
    public void greetingIsReturned() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(200, result.getResponse().getStatus());
        final var body = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assertThat(body.contains("Hello user! You are granted with "));
        assertThat(body.contains("ROLE_user"));
        assertThat(body.contains("ROLE_TESTER"));
    }
}
```

Cucumber JUnit 4 adapter:

```java
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:cucumber-features", plugin = {
        "pretty",
        "html:target/cucumber" }, extraGlue = "com.c4_soft.springaddons.samples.webmvc.cucumber.extraglue")
public class CucumberIntegrationTest {
}
```

Spring "extraglue":

```java
package com.c4_soft.springaddons.samples.webmvc.cucumber.extraglue;

...

@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SpringBootSampleApp.class })
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public static class CucumberSpringConfiguration {
}
```